# Inserting a formula in Pages is not possible

Tags: macos, pages

I would like to insert a formula in a Pages document (under El Capitan). But when I chose `Insert -> Formula` in the menu all entries in the submenu all entries are greyed out. Also `Insert -> MathType equation` is greyed out.

Do I need to install further software to have the options available?

**Clarification**

I am looking for a way to typeset a mathematical formula in a document (i.e., a kind of formula editor). Does any tool like this come together with Apple's office tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert a formula in normal text you need to download and install MathType.  Then that menu option should be available.

Comment: Hello Tom, thanks for your answer. Is there no way to typeset a mathematical formula only using Apple office tools (I don't want to buy an external tool)?

Comment: The trial of Mathtype is free and its capabilities even when expired suffice for many users.  Another possibility is the Grapher utility supplied with OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Functions and formulas can only be inserted into table cells. So, you have to insert a table first. If needed, the table can be configured in the Table section of the Inspector to consist of only a single cell: **1 row, 1 column, 0 header**. Also, the table can be set to have no border stroke/line.

If you are in a word processing document and want to position the table/formula freely on the page, you need to set the table to be a **floating** object (Inspector: Object Placement).

(This answer is based on Pages version 4.3, but might apply in principle to newer versions as well.)

User manual for Pages 5.5: http://help.apple.com/pages/mac/5.5/#/tana41710df7

Comment: Hello Dictionaries Anonymous, thanks for your answer. But actually my intention was to typeset a mathematical formula. I think I misinterpreted the menu button because I thought it's for starting a kind of formula editor. But now I see it's for inserting a tabular formula.